# How to keep event handlers alive in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, events, event-handling

I have a Flex app that connects to a JBoss/MS-SQL back-end.  Some of our customers have a proxy server in front of their JBoss with a timeout of 90 seconds.  In our application there are searches that can take up to 2-3 minutes for complex criteria.  Since the proxy isn't smart enough to recognize AMF's keep alive pings for what they are the proxy sends a 503 to the client, which in Flex land becomes a "Channel Call Failed" event.  In searching SO and other places, this seems to be a common problem.  We can't do anything about the proxy or lengthen the timeout, the application needs to handle it.

Of course the back-end continues to process and eventually ships the results to the client. But the user gets an ugly error message and assumes the app is broke.

The solution I have settled on is to consume the CCF error and have the client continue to wait.  I have managed the first part, but I can't figure out how to keep the client's handlers active to receive the data (and/or consume another timeout if necessary).

Current error handler:

```
private function handleSearchError(event : FaultEvent) : void {

    if (event.fault.faultCode == "Channel.Call.Failed") {
       event.stopImmediatePropagation();  // doesn't seem to help
       return;
    }

    if (searchProgress != null) {
        PopUpManager.removePopUp(searchProgress);
        searchProgress = null;
    }

    etc...
}
```

This is the setup:

```
<mx:Button id="btnSearch" label="
    {resourceManager.getString('recon_perspective',
    'ReconPerspective.ReconView.search')}" icon="{iconSearch}"
    click="handleSearch()" includeIn="search, default"/>
```

And:

```
<mx:method name="search" result="event.token.resultHandler(event);"
   fault="handleSearchError(event);"/>
```

Kicking off the call:

```
var token : AsyncToken = null;

token = sMSrv.search(searchType.toString(), getSearchMode(), criteria,
    smartMatchParent.isArchiveMode);

searchProgress = LoadProgress(PopUpManager.createPopUp
    (FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as DisplayObject, LoadProgress, true));
searchProgress.title = resourceManager.getString('matching', 'smartmatch.loading.trans');
searchProgress.token = token;
searchProgress.showCancelButton = true;
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(searchProgress);

token.resultHandler = handleSearchResults;
token.cancelSearch = false;
```

So my question is how do I keep handleSearch and handleSearchError alive to consume the events from the server?

I verified that the data comes back from the server using WebDeveloper in the browser to watch the network traffic and if you cause the app to refresh that screen, the data gets displayed.

Comment: Can you show the code that initiates the call? How have you determined that the client is actually receiving the data after the proxy times it out?

Comment: Wouldn't sending/receiving something every 15 (or whatever) seconds keep the connection open?  Set up a timer to do a simple meaningless post/response every 15 seconds until your main response comes so everything in-between the  backend and client knows it's still working.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that.  I put in a timer whose handler makes a trivial back-end call every 60 seconds, but that gets queued in the browser client until the search completes. So that's no help.

And as I mentioned, the regular AMF keep alive is treated as a different session by the proxy.

Comment: Can the application show progress?  Wouldn't reporting progress keep the channel open?  You should have something for your users anyways.  Showing them an overall percentage and/or tasks complete is required for good UX.

Comment: @moot yes, I could do that, that would be a more extensive application change than getting this working.  This is a large and mature project with more than the web interface, so fewer back-end changes the better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very in experienced but would this help?

```
private function handleSearchError(event : FaultEvent) : void {

if (event.fault.faultCode == "Channel.Call.Failed") {
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();  // doesn't seem to help
     if(event.isImmediatePropagationStopped(true)) {
         //After stopped do something here?
}

   return;
}

if (searchProgress != null) {
    PopUpManager.removePopUp(searchProgress);
    searchProgress = null;
}

etc...
```

}